# Why these python print commands behave differently with Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, string, byte

I noticed

```
$ python2 -c 'print("A"*20 + "\xef\xbe\xad\xde" + "A"*4)'
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAﾭ▒AAAA
```

and

```
$ python3 -c 'print("A"*20 + "\xef\xbe\xad\xde" + "A"*4)'
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAï¾­ÞAAAA
```

gives different output.

I'm expecting to have same string output with python3 as with python2

I tried to change from string to bytes using

```
$ python3 -c 'print(b"A"*20 + b"\xef\xbe\xad\xde" + b"A"*4)'
b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xef\xbe\xad\xdeAAAA'
```

but `b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\xef\xbe\xad\xdeAAAA'` is not `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAﾭ▒AAAA`

ie when piped to another process it's different.

Any idea how I can use Python3 to have same output than with Python 2 ?

Comment: Probably different character encoding.  Python3 applies encoding to both the program text and the output, and if they don't match you'll get garbled output.

Answer (score 1):

Python2 is sending the bytes directly to your console without interpretation.  Python3 is using Unicode codepoints in the string instead of bytes, and uses UTF-8 encoding to write them out.

You can get the same results in Python2:

```
print("A"*20 + "\xef\xbe\xad\xde" + "A"*4).decode('mbcs').encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: "and uses UTF-8 encoding to write them out" I believe that actually depends on the encoding of stdout which is based on your terminal settings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes it depends on at least a couple of factors, but in recent versions the default is UTF-8.  Except on Windows since 3.6, where the conversion to bytes is skipped entirely and UTF-16 is used with direct Windows API calls.

Comment: Ah, I do think just making it default to utf-8 would be the sane way to go about it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was only half right about 3.6 on Windows.  Yes it uses API calls with UTF-16, but first it uses UTF-8 and converts at the last minute.  See [PEP 528](https://peps.python.org/pep-0528/).  And I might have been premature on the rest, [PEP 686](https://peps.python.org/pep-0686/) says it won't happen until 3.15.

Comment: This code raises `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: Changing it to `$ python3 -c 'print((b"A"*20 + b"\xef\xbe\xad\xde" + b"A"*4).decode("mbcs"))'` raises `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
LookupError: unknown encoding: mbcs`

Comment: @BlackHemera which exact version of Python?  And I assume then you're not running this on Windows, so I don't know which encoding you should use.

Comment: `$ python3 --version` `Python 3.10.6`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `bytes` objects (which would be the equivalent of Python 2 `str`), and to write to the standard out directly (to the raw buffer, not the text i/o wrapper:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
>>> sys.stdout.buffer
<_io.BufferedWriter name='<stdout>'>
>>> stdout_raw = sys.stdout.buffer
>>> data = b"A"*20 + b"\xef\xbe\xad\xde" + b"A"*4 # notice I'm using bytes literals
>>> stdout_raw.write(data)
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAﾭ�AAAA28
```

Comment: I also find a solution like that... or as a one liner `python3 -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"A" * 20 + b"\xef\xbe\xad\xde" + b"A" * 4)'`. But I'm still looking for a solution with `print`